# Will Firebase API calls work on html pages loaded from my local file system?

Tags: firebase

...and not from a web server.

I am using my local file system to test the page and make most changes before deploying to the production web server.

Comment: Yes, it will work fine from localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they'll work provided you're not trying to do anything in the HTML that requires hosting in the first place such as accessing local geolocation data.